# Why is the code to change the color of a cell in vb.net different from vba?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

This may sound dumb but can someone explain the reason why I need to include this extra code in vb.net that I don't need in VBA when changing the color of a cell.
I wrote a program that creates and saves an excel file using the microsoft.office.interop reference. Here is my code:

```
Public Class Export_Excel_Class
Public excelapp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Public excelbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Public excelsheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

Public Sub newExcel()

    excelapp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    excelbook = excelapp.Workbooks.Add()
    excelsheet = excelbook.Sheets("sheet1")
    excelsheet.Range("A1").Select()
    excelsheet.Range("a1").AddComment("hello")
    excelsheet.Range("a1:B10").Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
    excelbook.SaveAs("C:\Users\DatOneBull\Desktop\Excel_Test")
    excelapp.Quit()

End Sub
```

On the line that sets the color I had originally had tried     `excelsheet.Range("a1:B10").Interior.Color =` 
and tried to set a color but the color proptery is read only. I found the solution online but there was no explanation. Can someone tell me what this section of code means and why it is able to set the color value of th range?

```
System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow)
```

Comment: Obviously the `Color` property is not read-only because you're setting it in the code you posted. The original issue would presumably have been that you were trying to assign a `System.Drawing.Color` value to a property that is not that type. That "extra code" is creating a value of the appropriate type, i.e. `Integer`, that represents the desired `System.Drawing.Color`.

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET stores colors differently to VBA. The `ToOle` function converts the VB.NET color to the equivalent VBA version. This is an example of [marshalling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)).

(If you are interested, the "OLE" in "ToOle" stands for "Object Linking and Embedding" which is an older way for windows programs to communicate with each other)

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, you would set the color something like this:

```
Range("A1").Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbYellow
' Or
Range("A2").Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 255, 0)
```

Note that I purposely fully qualified the VBA code.  This is valid VBA code, but in a style you rarely see.

In VB.Net you can do it like:

```
ws.Range("A1").Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbYellow
ws.Range("A2").Interior.Color = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.RGB(255, 255, 0)
```

essentially the same code.  Or you can do it like you are currently doing.

The net effect is the same; an integer value that represents color is being assigned to the Interior.Color property.  Either you use a function to compute that value, or you use a constant.   The various .Net functions are equivalents to the `VBA.RGB` function.  VBA knows nothing about colors defined as a `System.Drawing.Color`, hence a conversion function is necessary.